# Django CSRF token in template outdated after login

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

Django allows adding CSRF token to a webpage by rendering it to the template with `{% csrf_token %}`

Now here is the situation.

I have two tabs opened with public pages of my website which don't require a login and are viewing them as an anonymous user. Both tabs of course share the same *CSRF* token.
Now I perform user login using tab 1. This triggers the rotation of the *CSRF* token and updates the cookie with the new token.

This means the *CSRF* token rendered to the webpage of tab 2 is now outdated. So any further *POST* or *AJAX* requests sent from tab 2 will return 403, making my website on tab 2 behave incorrectly until I reload the page.

Does this mean, that to avoid this problem I should never rely on `{% csrf_token %}` and always retrieve the *CSRF* token from the cookie before posting any ajax requests?

This sounds a little strange so maybe I'm missing something.
I was expecting `{% csrf_token %}` to be a reliable source of the *CSRF* token, but seems like it is not.